# How to get all place name translations in Nominatim?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

OpenStreetMap supports different name translations for places. For example "Moscow" in English and "Москва" in Russian for the same node. But there are also French, German, Bahasa translations and so on. Is there a way to get all these translations in a single request? I know I can use "accept_language" property on a "reverse" request, but in will only return a single translation, and I'd like to get all available translations in one request. Fast googling didn't return any results. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `osm_type` and `osm_id` fields to retrieve the original OSM element.

Example: The [Nominatim query for Moscow](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Moscow&format=json) will return `osm_type: relation` and `osm_id: 2555133` for the first result. Based on this information we can look at the [original OSM element](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2555133) or perform an [OSM API query for this element](https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2555133). This will include all `name:<lang>` tags.

Note: Make sure to look both at the [Nominatim usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) and [OSM API usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_usage_policy) before running automated queries!